# LWC: Invalid event type "WireContextEvent" dispatched in element

Tags: lightning-web-components, service-cloud-console, console, custom-console-components

**Updated the question:**

We are using custom Lightning Console App. Here is a simplified version of our LWC to explain the problem. Any idea?

*sampleWireContextEventWarning.html*

```
    <template>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Brand action" title="Brand action" 
            onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"
        ></lightning-button>
    </template>
```

*sampleWireContextEventWarning.js*

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class SampleWireContextEventWarning extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    handleClick(event){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: "500r0000004QblbAAC",
                objectApiName: "Case",
                actionName: "view"
            },
        });
    }
}
```

When I include this component to a page in App Builder and click on the button, I could see the navigation to the Case Record happening, but I could still see the warning in the browser console.

> [LWC warning]: Invalid event type "WireContextEvent" dispatched in
>   element . Event name should only
>   contain lowercase alphanumeric characters.
>    aura_proddebug.js:242 at
>   SampleWireContextEventWarning.dispatchEvent
>   (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs32/auraFW/javascript/NlYMGsCv2IRRXpX5txmc5Q/aura_proddebug.js:7245:28)
>   aura_proddebug.js:242 at SampleWireContextEventWarning.wrappedMethod
>   [as dispatchEvent]
>   (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs32/auraFW/javascript/NlYMGsCv2IRRXpX5txmc5Q/aura_proddebug.js:19687:31)
>   aura_proddebug.js:242 at t.get
>   (https://micps--cpsuat.lightning.force.com/components/laf/contextService.js:2:1896)
>   aura_proddebug.js:242 at m
>   (https://micps--cpsuat.lightning.force.com/components/laf/contextService.js:2:1204)
>   aura_proddebug.js:242 at n
>   (https://micps--cpsuat.lightning.force.com/components/laf/contextService.js:2:1389)
>   aura_proddebug.js:242 at Object.a.getContextValues
>   (https://micps--cpsuat.lightning.force.com/components/laf/contextService.js:2:3199)
>   aura_proddebug.js:242 at d
>   (https://micps--cpsuat.lightning.force.com/components/laf/navigationService.js:2:192) aura_proddebug.js:242 at i.navigateTo
>   (https://micps--cpsuat.lightning.force.com/components/laf/navigationService.js:2:611) aura_proddebug.js:242 at SampleWireContextEventWarning.[Navigate]
>   (https://micps--cpsuat.lightning.force.com/components/force/navigation.js:2:415)

Comment: Please post the messages from the console as text instead of a screenshot. Thanks

Comment: The error message is very succinct, what about it confuses you? Also, please provide more code to show what exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @gNerb.. I've updated the question with a sample component. Is the warning still succinct?

Comment: This is a much better question, good job on your update. The update does show that what you see is a warning and not an error. This means that it is probably not that big of a deal. You show here that the navigation does in fact happen. As far as I can tell, the code you have posted here works. This would mean that your issue lies somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Agree. I ruled out the possibility of something else causing this warning. If I just comment out the "this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]..." line in the JS file, then the warning does NOT appear. So it has something to do with this line.

Comment: Did you try to use `evt.preventDefault()` and `evt.stopPropagation()`, like in the [last example of the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/use_navigate_basic)?

Comment: Please try to run application with debug mode in disable mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LWCs are not fully supported in the Console at the time. You will need to put your LWC in an Aura Component wrapper for it to work. See the [LWC Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_experiences) for more on this. I would expect this to be the source of the errors you are seeing.

From the Docs:

> Lightning Web Components doesn’t currently support these Salesforce experiences and tools. To use a Lightning web component with these experiences and tools, wrap the component in an Aura component.
>
> - Lightning Out
> - Lightning Components for Visualforce
> - Standalone Apps
> - Salesforce Console (Navigation Item API, Workspace API, UtilityBar API)
> - Utility Bars
> - URL Addressable Tabs
> - Flows
> - Snap-ins Chat
> - Lightning for Gmail, Outlook Integration
> - EMP API, Conversation Toolkit API, Omni Toolkit API, Quick Action API
> - Standard Action Overrides, Custom Actions, Global Actions, List View Actions, Related List View Actions
> - Chatter Extensions

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev.. probably this is the reason for the warnings..

Comment: If you've not put your LWC in an aura component wrapper, I think you can pretty much count on it. They're not expected to work properly at this time in the console.